# what is the Authentication token used for when signing into a web page with google?

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-signin

hello everyone ive been working on making a website for a change and when I log into my website with google, I'm also using drive rest api, I get the token

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
  ...
}
```

but when I stored this token in my database and tried to query the token with a new instance of a token they didn't match, so I'm wondering what this token is for if it isn't a token to tell me that the user is the same as a past user with the same login, thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

The token is encrypted and you are expected to receive different one every time you request. You can decrypt it using a library of your favorite programming language, **verify it** then use `sub` parameter as a user id.

Check out details in [this doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth).